# Error in selecting data from attribute table QGIS

Tags: qgis

First of all, I'm not sure why all the data points from my csv file do not show up on QGIS. I enabled custom delimiters to commas and still have no clue, it worked for my other vector layers except this one.

Next, I seem to encounter an error selecting data. I want data from rainfall of higher than 46.5mm and temperatures of 29.5 mm to show up but it shows an error message.

I typed this

```
"Average temperature"  >= 29.5 AND  "Total Rainfall (mm)"  >= 46.5
```

but receive an error for this

```
Parser Error:
syntax error, unexpected COLUMN_REF, expecting $end

Eval Error:
No root node! Parsing failed?
```

---

```
52  26.7    16.5    17179.3 46712.2
52  25.6    21.4    29670.4 28489.8
52  25.9    27.5    25703.5 30676.4
52  26.7    26.9    34384.5 32161.3
```

Comment: Are those columns from the CSV file that failed to load?

Comment: I think you've got 2 issues: 1) csv not loading correctly and 2) problem with querying attributes. Could you split up the questions. Something that might help with Q1 is to add a few rows from the csv in your question.

Comment: Im not sure whether its because it's failed to load or whether it's not showing up but when i opened the attribute table, all the data is there. it's probably only not showing up on the map.

Comment: btw, in the data above, the big numbers in decimals are coordinates. X and Y.

Comment: Have you selected the 4th and 5th column for X and Y, and selcted a projected CRS (not WGS84 latlong, but probably Singapore TM)?

Answer (score 2):

The data sample you posted certainly is not comma delimited. It might be tab delimited. Try that. If it does not work, please post a screenshot of the attribute table.